# Display: none for dynamic selects and inputs on a page... Is this a good or bad idea

Tags: html, css

I have a "back office" page i am developing. I have created a series of buttons that turn divs on and off for the various functions of the office.

example buttons: change name, change date, create a new widget etc...

rather than load a new page with the proper forms and data I load it all up front and then hide it with

```
display: none;
```

when you want to perform a certain task, the button turns on that div..

```
display: block;
```

Is this ok or a hair brained idea sure to break at some point..

Thank you.

Comment: It depends if you want to hide stuff from your users or not.

Comment: I am only hiding the areas they are not using. They are like switches. turn on the "update my company" and all you see is that div with the form. Turn on "create my ad campaign" and update dive hides and ad campaign div comes on.

Comment: I meant more so from a security standpoint.  Is someone going to be able to hack this form to upload data.  Or is having all of this exposed going to lead to other security concerns?

Comment: Oh, i see.. Well I authenticate the user, and they are paying clients. Plus I have put in place checks on all forms to insure proper form entry ---client side and server side. The data exposed is minimal if you view source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hairbrained and sure to break eventually, but if it meets your needs for data integrity / security and performance and you are OK with fixing it when / as things change, then it sounds like a solution that fits your needs (whatever those actually are)